# Словить нажатие клавиш, не выполняя их действие

Tags: c#, winforms, .net

Добрый день, хэшкодеры.

В форме есть несколько десятков TextBox'ов, в них обработка KeyUP и KeyDown, результат которой - вывод в том же текстбоксе нажатой клавиши с модификатором (если он есть). Пример: я щелкаю по текстбоксу и нажимаю шифт+f, в самом текстбоксе появится "Shift+F".

Такая своеобразная запись горячих клавиш, которые приложение потом может использовать. Проблема в том, что при нажатии (к примеру) сочетания WIN+R открывается окошко "Выполнить...", забирает фокус на себя, и не дает ничего записать в текстбокс, он остается пустым. Или если попробовать ввести комбинацию Alt+%anykey%, фокус тут же убежит на menuStrip (верхняя панелька с "файл", "правка" и т.п.) и опять же ничего не запишется. И даже Tab нажать нельзя, т.к. фокус  перекинется на следующий элемент формы (и свойство TabStop тоже не помогает).

Отсюда вопрос: можно ли как то заблокировать действия клавиш, пока фокус на текстбоксе?

У текстбокса есть свойство ShortcutsEnabled, но MSDN говорит, что он отключает только те горячие клавиши, что нужны для работы с текстом.

Comment: Погуглите "winform intercept alt tab keys" или что-то подобное. На SO есть несколько ответов. В основном ответы про установку хуков.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188966.aspx) всё подробно расписано.

А вообще как то так:

```
internal static class HookManager
{

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
  private struct KeyboardHookStruct
  {    
    public byte VirtualKeyCode;    
    public int ScanCode;   
    public int Flags;    
    public int Time;    
    public int ExtraInfo;
  }

  private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;  
  private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;  
  private const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;  
  private static int keyboardHookHandle; 
  private static HookProc keyboardDelegate; 
  private static Action<string, Keys> customAction;  
  public delegate int HookProc(int nCode, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
  private static extern int SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hInstance, int threadId);

  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
  private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(int idHook);

  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  private static extern int CallNextHookEx(int idHook, int nCode, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

  public static bool StopMonitoring()
  {
    bool result = UnhookWindowsHookEx(keyboardHookHandle);

    keyboardHookHandle = 0;
    keyboardDelegate = null;
    if (!result)
      return false;
    return true;
  }

  public static bool StartMonitoring(Action<string, Keys> keyboardCustomAction)
  {
    if (keyboardCustomAction == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException();
    keyboardDelegate = KeyboardHookProc;   
    IntPtr instance = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.BaseAddress;
    keyboardHookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyboardDelegate, instance, 0);
    customAction = keyboardCustomAction;
    if (keyboardHookHandle == 0)
      return false;
    return true;
  }

  private static int KeyboardHookProc(int nCode, int wParam, IntPtr lParam)
  {
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {

      KeyboardHookStruct keyboardHookData = (KeyboardHookStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(KeyboardHookStruct));
      if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN)
      {
        string text = Encoding.Default.GetString(new byte[] { keyboardHookData.VirtualKeyCode });        
        if (customAction != null)
          customAction(text, (Keys)keyboardHookData.VirtualKeyCode);
      }
    }
    else
      return CallNextHookEx(keyboardHookHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);    
    return -1;
  }    
}
```

Пример использования:

```
var keyHandler = new Action<string, Keys>( (text, keyInfo) => {  
  if (keyInfo == Keys.Back)
    ProcessBackspace();
  else if (keyInfo == Keys.Enter || keyInfo == Keys.Return)
    ProcessEnter();
  else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) 
    ProcessText(text);
});
HookManager.StartMonitoring(keyHandler);
HookManager.StopMonitoring();
```

Comment: то что нужно, спасибо